# How to repair the broken stitching and seams in my leather boots?

Tags: boots, repairs

After several years of abuse and poor care my boots have completely gone at the seams around the inner ankle (see photos)

[image]
[image]

What can I do to repair my boots? My current plan is to just get some thick thread and just resow them, but I am concerned about whether they will be at all waterproof afterwards. Is there anything else I should do/consider?

My boots are leather and made by Meindl if it makes any difference

P.S yes, I should definitely look after my boots better so they don't get in this state, but ts a bit late now...

Comment: I've also got some leather boots that need some TLC to keep going, but my issue is cracks in the leather around the toe, mostly where it bends, not busted stitching. Been brainstorming some solutions for a while, but was hoping to get a some solid info before I take a chance in ruining my currently still functional boots. Curious to see what we get.

Comment: It looks like the leather at the split seam is either dried out or rotted? If the leather is dried out, try to use mink oil or Obenauf's leather oil to soften leather in order for the stitching to hold. It may be too late, I cannot see the boots close enough.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your best bet for sewing is to use a [Speedy Stitcher](http://www.speedystitcher.com/).  The thick gauged thread works really well in boot/shoe repairs and is easy to use.  You will be punching holes through the leather which creates potential for water to invade, but the waxy thread helps eliminate this issue.

I would finish up with a coat of [Sno-Seal](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00CQJDQ90), which is a great way to help waterproof while also conditioning the leather.

Even with the holes you create sewing it up you will still have a good pair of boots that are perfect for your feet.  A little water is easily manageable.

Comment: I was going to suggest coating your thread with bees wax to sew them. But this waxy thread He is mentioning might be better.  Cracked leather? I have found that silicone spray keeps them from cracking further. This is a industrial spray. Like small ball bearings used to make things slide across a surface smooth & fast. . But not water proof. Be hard to find in a store. Unless industrial supply.

Answer (score 3):

I have a similar problem with two great pairs of waterproof leather boots, with seams un-stitching alongside the ball of the foot.

[GearAid Freesole](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Mcnett-117570-Freesole-Shoe-Repair/dp/B007UTZXT2) is a tough flexible urethane repair highly recommended to re-bond the leather seams tightly instead of trying to sew them. A tube of this was 6.50 CAD at MEC.

Comment: Hi and Welcome to TGO. It would be interesting to know what the result was for you while using Freesole.

Answer (score 2):

I used some quick drying glue (a glue gun will work if you have one handy) to hold the seams together then after letting the glue dry overnight I picked up some rubber cement (the same stuff we used to patch bicycle tires as a kid) and spread the rubber cement along the both sides of the seam and between the two pieces of leather where the stitching came apart.  Let the rubber cement dry for another 24 hours.  The rubber cement is holding up very well and it's flexible as well so no cracking of the rubber cement.  It's -20 degrees Celsius outside and snowing and my boots are still warm and comfortable and waterproof as well. For a $3.00 fix it's working out pretty good and the boots should last 1 or 2 more winters.  If you are the person who care about what your boots look like this fix isn't for you.  However, if you just want to repair a pair of expensive leather work boots this fix works excellent for boots that you want to use for another 2 years.